# How to insert bootstrap col in summernote editor and I want to add it into the data that is coming from database

Tags: jquery, html, summernote

> Hey Friends, Pardon for my English, I'm working on a project where I
>   need to insert an bootstrap grid column in a row(append just after
>   last column) in summernote and there is a bootstrap row with some
>   columns, already exist in summernote editor from database.

I'm little confused with the jquery part.. Please help me. Please see following code:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm text-dark" href="javascript:void;" id="inserGridWithOption"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> Insert Grid</a>

<textarea class="form-control summernote" rows="6" placeholder="Enter product short summery or description" name="homerow6col1" id="homerow6col1">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <p class="text-center border p-3 ReasonToBuyBlockEntry">
    This is column - 1
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <p class="text-center border p-3 ReasonToBuyBlockEntry">
    This is column - 2
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</textarea>

<script>
 $('#inserGridWithOption').click(function(){
  var markupStr = '<div class="col-md-4"> <p class="text-center border p-3 ReasonToBuyBlockEntry"> This is a new column.</p></div>';
  var res = $('#homerow6col1').summernote('code');
  $('#homerow6col1').summernote('code', res + markupStr );
 });
</script>
```

> What I want that It insert or append a column in existing row every
>   time when I click on "Insert Grid" button. See result/output should be
>   like following code where I highlighted desired output with some
>   "####" :

```
<textarea class="form-control summernote" rows="6" placeholder="Enter product short summery or description" name="homerow6col1" id="homerow6col1">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <p class="text-center border p-3 ReasonToBuyBlockEntry">
    This is column - 1
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <p class="text-center border p-3 ReasonToBuyBlockEntry">
    This is column - 2
   </p>
  </div>
  ######## Following code should be inserted########
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <p class="text-center border p-3 ReasonToBuyBlockEntry">
    This is a new column.
   </p>
  </div>
  ######## Above code should be inserted ########
 </div>
</textarea>
```